# autoconf & c++ & obsolete headers

Tags: c++, autoconf

Some code I have runs into the following with modern C++. Of course, there's a better way to express this in modern C++. Question is, how to use automake to set a CPP macro for conditionalization?

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/ext/hash_map:60,
                 from grapes.hpp:54,
                 from broadmerger.hpp:22,
                 from broadmerger.cpp:16:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/backward/backward_warning.h:28: error: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.
```

Answer (score 1):

The libstdc++ manual has a section on this topic  (["Extension headers hash_map, hash_set moved to ext or backwards"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/backwards.html#id507836))